# Java - Refactor similar classes

Tags: java, refactoring

I have this 4 classes, almost the same with only difference the type of  `building` parameter.

Is there some way to refactor/merge `class Building` and `class NewBuilding` to one.
I tried creating a generic class but `sBuilding.getSomething()` then is not valid.

```
public class Building {

static void doSomething(SearchBuilding sBuilding) {
        if (sBuilding.getSomething()) {
            useBuilding(sBuilding);
        }
    }

}

public class NewBuilding {

static void doSomething(SearchNewBuilding sBuilding) {
        if (sBuilding.getSomething() ){
            useBuilding(sBuilding);
        }
    }
}


public class SomeBuilding {

    private final SearchBuilding building;

    protected SearchBuilding getBuilding() {
        return building;
    }

    protected void applyBuilding() {
        Building.doSomething(getBuilding());
    }
}

public class SomeNewBuilding {

    private final SearchNewBuilding building;

    protected SearchNewBuilding getBuilding() {
        return building;
    }

    protected void applyBuilding() {
        NewBuilding.doSomething( getBuilding());
    }

}
```

Comment: It's hard to say if this is viable, because you're using a contrived example here, but the typical solution would be to have a base class `BaseBuilding`, then refer to the base class type everywhere, and have any other Building directly inherit from the base class. Do all building  types have the same set of methods?

Comment: why are those methods static?

Comment: Really not complicated at all. Implement a common interface... `SomeBuilding implements FooBuilding` and `doSomething(FooBuilding building)`

Comment: By the way, that example is absolutely awful. You have abstracted away all of the details, which is good, but the result is completely incoherent.

Comment: @Michael if I do `doSomething(FooBuilding building)` then Im loosing the functionality of `SearchBuilding `

Comment: @Carcigenicate yes the same, but with difference `SearchBuilding` and `SearchNewBuilding` data classes .